ASR Model Tokenizer Won't Load
I’m trying to load the ASR model ‘facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53’ so I made this simple script to test:
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor

# Define the model name
model_name = "facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53"

# Download the processor and the model
processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained(model_name)
processor.save_pretrained("wav2vec2_model")
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained(model_name)
model.save_pretrained("wav2vec2_model")

print("Model and processor downloaded and saved locally.")


But I kept getting this error:
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53'.
If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models',
make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise,
make sure 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53' is the correct path to a
directory containing all relevant files for a Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer tokenizer.

I’ve tried clearing the cache and tried using ‘AutoProcessor’ instead of ‘Wav2Vec2Processor’, but the issue still persists. Has anyone seen this error and know how to resolve this issue?

OSError in from_pretrained usually occurs when a folder already exists with the same name, as suggested in the error message. In this case, huggingface tries to load it locally and fails because is it not a valid model directory, see this thread. This issue seems to also be connected to your transformers version, so if the problem persists you could try updating the package to the latest version.

I tried updating transformers, testing this out on an empty server, clearing the cache, as well as other solutions in that thread. I don't know what else to do.

Looking more closely I think the issue might be that specifically for that model the processor is not saved under that model_id on the model hub, check out https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10696.

This makes sense, thanks!
